# oracle10g hibernate problem

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, connection-pooling, ora-00923

when my app startup, i get error like below, can anyone elaborate what i missed out? the app running fine when using mysql. do i miss out any extra parameter in config.xml file?

```
2009-08-17 11:32:12,294 [main] INFO [info.jtrac.config.DataSourceFactoryBean] -
Not using embedded HSQLDB or JNDI datasource, switching on Apache DBCP data sour
ce connection pooling
2009-08-17 11:32:14,826 [main] WARN [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] -
 SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2009-08-17 11:32:14,826 [main] ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter]
- Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found whe
re expected
)
2009-08-17 11:32:14,826 [main] WARN [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] - Could
not obtain connection metadata
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFact
ory (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSou
rce.java:1225)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource
.java:880)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.
getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:
84)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009
)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.jav
a:1292)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSession
Factory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:799)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessi
onFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:733)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPr
opertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1257)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:438)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:940)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:940)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:394)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:736)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:369)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationCon
text(ContextLoader.java:261)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationConte
xt(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitiali
zed(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
t.java:3843)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4
342)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:77
1)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.ja
va:627)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.j
ava:553)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1149)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:5
16)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expect
ed

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.ja
va:74)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:1
10)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:171)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1030)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:
774)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.jav
a:849)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStateme
nt.java:1186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:
1377)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatemen
tWrapper.java:386)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingSt
atement.java:208)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(
PoolableConnectionFactory.java:332)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(Bas
icDataSource.java:1249)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSou
rce.java:1221)
        ... 72 more
2009-08-17 11:32:16,826 [main] WARN [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] -
 SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2009-08-17 11:32:16,826 [main] ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter]
- Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found whe
re expected
)
2009-08-17 11:32:16,841 [main] WARN [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] -
 SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2009-08-17 11:32:16,841 [main] ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter]
- Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found whe
re expected
)
2009-08-17 11:32:17,154 [main] WARN [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCo
desFactory] - Error while extracting database product name - falling back to emp
ty error codes
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connecti
on for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.Cannot
GetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is o
rg.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFacto
ry (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(Jd
bcUtils.java:198)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(Jd
bcUtils.java:225)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(S
QLErrorCodesFactory.java:216)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.s
etDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:147)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<
init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:110)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.newJdbcExcepti
onTranslator(SessionFactoryUtils.java:143)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.getDefaultJdbcEx
ceptionTranslator(HibernateAccessor.java:453)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernate
AccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(Hibernat
eTemplate.java:378)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTe
mplate.java:866)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTe
mplate.java:858)
        at info.jtrac.hibernate.HibernateJtracDao.createSchema(HibernateJtracDao
.java:524)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1257)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:438)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:940)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:219)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver
.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:117)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1172)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:940)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:383)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:242)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:394)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:736)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:369)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationCon
text(ContextLoader.java:261)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationConte
xt(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitiali
zed(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
t.java:3843)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4
342)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:77
1)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.ja
va:627)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.j
ava:553)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1149)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:5
16)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedExcept
ion: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found
where expected
)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(Dat
aSourceUtils.java:82)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(Jd
bcUtils.java:185)
        ... 76 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableCon
nectionFactory (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSou
rce.java:1225)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource
.java:880)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(D
ataSourceUtils.java:113)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(Dat
aSourceUtils.java:79)
        ... 77 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expect
ed

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.ja
va:74)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:1
10)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java
:171)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1030)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:
774)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CStatement.jav
a:849)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStateme
nt.java:1186)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:
1377)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatemen
tWrapper.java:386)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingSt
atement.java:208)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(
PoolableConnectionFactory.java:332)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(Bas
icDataSource.java:1249)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSou
rce.java:1221)
        ... 80 more
2009-08-17 11:32:19,294 [main] WARN [info.jtrac.hibernate.HibernateJtracDao] - e
xpected database schema does not exist, will create. Error is: Hibernate operati
on: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state
[null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00923: FROM
 keyword not found where expected
); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
 PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
)
```

my config look like this

```
database.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
database.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.0.23:1521:appsdev
database.username=jtrac_testonly
database.password=jtrac_testonly
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging from the exception, [validationQuery](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html) specified in your Commons DBCP configuration is invalid in Oracle.

Comment: Agreed. The validation query is normally something along the lines of SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

Comment: i change the validationQuery to "SELECT 1+1" but still getting the same error. what validationQuery should i use for oracle?

Comment: `select 1 from dual` as suggested by pjp above should work fine for Oracle. If you're still getting an error it must be something else - are you sure it's the same error?

Comment: In my case (converting a mySQL example to run on Oracle) - the validatiokn query that the sample used was 'SELECT 1' - and as @pjp pointed out oracle needs to be 'select 1 from dual'

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you have a problem connecting to the database.

1. You should verify your connection urls...
2. If everything looks fine, I would enter the same connection data into a database tool, to check if the tool can connect.

Most of the times, there two steps should find 90% of all connection problems.

Comment: "database tool" what is that? tool from hibernate?  by the way, when my app, run it able to create tables in oracle. but i dont understand why i throw error like above